# Is there a way to get last selected position with current selected position from recyclerview android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, calendar

I'm currently using recyclerview to build a custom calendar for an android app.
This app is contains elements about schedule management, and that raised a demand to make multiple date selection via recyclerview.

Current layout is:
[image]

recyclerview only holds the numbers in the calendar. All texts are made in TextView, and is aligned via GridLayout and LinearLayout.

Recyclerview adapter code:

```
package com.example.mymate

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.mymate.databinding.ListitemCalendarBinding
import java.time.LocalDate

class CalendarAdapter(val context: Context, val dayList: ArrayList<LocalDate?>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarAdapter.DayViewHolder>() {

    class DayViewHolder(val binding: ListitemCalendarBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: String, color: String) {
            val day = binding.dayText
            val spend = binding.billText
            day.text = item
            spend.text = item
            //text color
            if (color == "blue") {
                day.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
            } else if (color == "red") {
                day.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DayViewHolder {
        val binding = ListitemCalendarBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
        return DayViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dayList.size
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DayViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var day = dayList[position]
        var daytext = ""
        if (dayList[position] == null) {
            daytext = ""
        } else {
            daytext = day?.dayOfMonth.toString()
        }
        if ((position + 1) % 7 == 0) {
            holder.bind(daytext, "blue")
        } else if (position == 0 || position % 7 == 0) {
            holder.bind(daytext, "red")
        } else {
            holder.bind(daytext, "black")
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            var iYear = day?.year
            var iMonth = day?.month
            var iDay = day?.dayOfMonth
            var fullday = day


            //TODO: item click event
        }
    }
}
```

There's no other features yet planned, so click event is practically empty.

Is there any way to get the position for selected item along with the position of the item that selected before? I'm struggling to get last selected position info, and access to the item via position to change background color, text, etc, for the items between the selected item and the selected item before.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, Maybe this way? declare two variables in the adapter:

```
var beforeSelectedPosition = -1
var lastSelectedPosition = -1
```

And on the `setOnClickListener` do this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
    // Other codes
    
    if(lastSelectedPosition == -1) {
        lastSelectedPosition = holder.absoluteAdapterPosition
    }else {
        beforeSelectedPosition = lastPositionSelected
        lastPositionSelected = holder.absoluteAdapterPosition
    }
}
```

Whenever you need, just call `adapter.lastPositionSelected` and `adapter.beforeSelectedPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous selected index in a variable. And, in onClick check if there is some previous selected index, if so mark the list items selected.

If you want to reset the state on third click, which it seems as you want to select a range of dates. So, the third time click happens, you would want to start the selection again. Below is a sample code :

Store previous selected index

```
var previousSelectedIndex = -1;
```

Implement onClick listener

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
    if(previousSelectedIndex == -1) {
        previousSelectedIndex = holder.absoluteAdapterPosition
        reset() // here you reset any selected items
    }else {
        // method to mark your items selected between previous index and current index
        selectItems(previousSelectedIndex, holder.absoluteAdapterPosition)
        
        // once you have selected items, we reset the previous index to -1
        // so that on third click user can start selection again
        previousSelectedIndex = -1
    }
}
```

PS: If this for some booking kind of app and those are check-in and check-out dates, or a case where the next date should be later than the previous date, you may want to add additional checks such that, current index > previous index.